# import google contact and parse image code

Tags: html, json, image, parsing, decode

my script for importing gmail contacts work as well , it return name , email , and image but i dont know how to display the image in the html tag . the code json of image returned is like this:

```
"ôÆÔÔmr½k/8I16¹&ÂÂæöì=†çlk'qËüoÍÒ8äLåLŽáZ³GrF§i)%@’ŽHÔ6ØØ•Âþds˜%h¤‚Ÿ2¨‘Þ—ÖyDÛVºbè¢ýCEuî*RT´l« Ã)GúAËÑï |Îå¹¡XÝÍ-Clr¡Y½’aòg°ùl{Tã‘ÔYúHÁRŠÁ2EKP"7Ô¢R]‹(keëà‡Ž5YÎf­ÈÖ^JÈÈUâ%C´&ü—b¥¹l,Nþã0ÏÂ|CauÒ,°H5#¯CØ‚:†SpÊÖA0ñ€ÂqG|Ûø§.o,ÔW9u×W"²¨‘‘•HÔÄ)TˆÑ?"
```

Thanks!!! :))

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please could you provide the script so that we can see what might be wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
     $return = array();
   if (!empty($contacts['feed']['entry'])) {
    foreach($contacts['feed']['entry'] as $contact) {

        //retrieve user photo
        if (isset($contact['link'][0]['href'])) {

            $url =   $contact['link'][0]['href'];

            $url = $url . '&access_token=' . urlencode($accesstoken);

            $curl = curl_init($url);

            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

            $image = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
        }
        $return[] = array (
            'name'=> $contact['title']['$t'],
            'email' => $contact['gd$email'][0]['address'],
            'image' =>$image,
        );


    }               
}

    foreach ($return as $contact) {

        $image=$contact['image'];
        echo $image;?>
        <br> <br> <br>
        <img  src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo $image ?>" /> <br>;
        <?php
    }
```